# TemplateSyntaxError in Django app

Tags: python, django, django-models, facebook, django-templates

Hi i was trying to implement facebook login for my django app using django-facebook connect using Ajax. I was following this link for implementing it [facebook-django integration with ajax](http://teebes.com/blog/13/django-facebook-connect-integration-with-ajax-no-middleware). On doing so i am hit with this error " TemplateSyntaxError at /registrationForm/

'facebookconnect' is not a valid tag library: Template library facebookconnect not found, tried django.templatetags.facebookconnect,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.facebookconnect,facebookconnect.templatetags.facebookconnect ". I will paste my error log here. Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://10.1.0.90:8080/registrationForm/
Django Version: 1.2.5
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'universityDetails',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'captcha',
 'facebookconnect',
 'social_auth']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
 'universityDB.FacebookConnectMiddleware.FacebookConnectMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'facebook.djangofb.FacebookMiddleware',
 'facebookconnect.middleware.FacebookConnectMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/ravi/Desktop/universityDB/templates/registrationForm.html, error at line 75
   'facebookconnect' is not a valid tag library: Template library facebookconnect not found, tried django.templatetags.facebookconnect,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.facebookconnect,facebookconnect.templatetags.facebookconnect
   65 :   <p style="clear:both;float:left;">


   66 :     <input type="submit" value="Log in" />


   67 :     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


   68 :     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a HREF="http://10.1.0.90:8080/forgotPassword/">Forgotten your password?</a></p>


   69 :   </div>


   70 : </form>


   71 : <br>


   72 : 


   73 : <p>Login via facebook!</p>


   74 : 


   75 :  {% load facebookconnect %} 


   76 : {% facebook_connect_login_button %}


   77 : 


   78 : {% facebook_connect_script %}


   79 : 


   80 : 


   81 : 


   82 : <br>


   83 : <br>


   84 : <br>


   85 : <br>


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/ravi/Desktop/universityDB/../universityDB/universityDetails/views.py" in registrationForm
  50.     return render_to_response("registrationForm.html")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  181.         t = get_template(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  157.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  134.             source, display_name = loader(name, dirs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in __call__
  42.         return self.load_template(template_name, template_dirs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in load_template
  48.             template = get_template_from_string(source, origin, template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template_from_string
  168.     return Template(source, origin, name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in __init__
  158.         self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in compile_string
  186.     return parser.parse()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in parse
  282.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in load
  928.                                       (taglib, e))

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /registrationForm/
Exception Value: 'facebookconnect' is not a valid tag library: Template library facebookconnect not found, tried django.templatetags.facebookconnect,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.facebookconnect,facebookconnect.templatetags.facebookconnect
```

My directory structure is

```
universityDB/   
        universityDetails
           models.py
           views.py
           urls.py
        templates/
                xd_receiver.htm
        templatetags/
        __init__.py
        facebookconnect.py
```

and my facebookconnect.py is

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

register = template.Library()

class FacebookScriptNode(template.Node):
        def render(self, context):
            return """
            <script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript"> FB.init("%s", "%s");
                function facebook_onlogin() {
                    var uid = FB.Facebook.apiClient.get_session().uid;
                    var session_key = FB.Facebook.apiClient.get_session().session_key;
                    var expires = FB.Facebook.apiClient.get_session().expires;
                    var secret = FB.Facebook.apiClient.get_session().secret;
                    var sig = FB.Facebook.apiClient.get_session().sig;

                    fb_connect_ajax(expires, session_key, secret, uid, sig);

                }

                function fb_connect_ajax(expires, session_key, ss, user, sig) {

                    var post_string = 'expires=' + expires;
                    post_string = post_string + '&session_key=' + session_key;
                    post_string = post_string + '&ss=' + ss;
                    post_string = post_string + '&user=' + user;
                    post_string = post_string + '&sig=' + sig;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "%s",
                        data: post_string,
                        success: function(msg) {
                            window.location = '%s'; //.reload()
                        }
                    });
                } 
            </script>       
            """ % (settings.FACEBOOK_API_KEY, reverse('xd_receiver'), reverse('facebook_connect_ajax'), settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)


def facebook_connect_script(parser, token): return FacebookScriptNode()

register.tag(facebook_connect_script)

class FacebookLoginNode(template.Node):
    def render(self, context): 
        return "<fb:login-button onlogin='facebook_onlogin();'></fb:login-button>"

def facebook_connect_login_button(parser, token): return FacebookLoginNode()

register.tag(facebook_connect_login_button)
```

Comment: Is it `facebookConnect.py` or `facebookconnect.py`?

Comment: it is facebookconnect.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `facebookConnect.py` file must be within your `templatetags` package (it must have an `__init__.py` to make it a package).

It also appears that in your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` setting, you've added `facebookconnect`, even though that isn't an app (going by your directory structure). Instead, you should have `universityDB.universityDetails` listed as an app.

Comment: wat should be the content for _init_.py file ? facebookconnect.py is inside my templatetags folder

Comment: i added universityDB.universityDetails to my installed apps, and added and _init_.py file inside templatetags. Now i am getting this error "AlreadyRegistered at /registrationForm/

The model UniversityDetails is already registered"

Comment: It sounds like you're importing `models.py` in two separate ways, old-style, and absolute. If you import a module via an absolute path (e.g. `import universityDB.universityDetails.models`) and then import it via the old-style (e.g. in `universityDB/universityDetails/views.py` you do `import models`) the module will actually be imported twice! Don't do this!

Comment: i changed it now..but still having the same old error.."facebookconnect' is not a valid tag library: Template library facebookconnect not found, tried django.templatetags.facebookconnect,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.facebookconnect,facebookconnect.templatetags.facebookconnect"

Comment: Make sure you don't have syntax errors or similar problems in your module. Open a shell `python manage.py shell` and import your module: `import universityDB.universityDetails.templatetags.facebookconnect`

Comment: hey..i got that fixed..but do u have any idea how to redirect the page after logging in with facebook id ? i am getting redirected to the same home page where i logs in ...

Comment: Accept this answer, and make a new question.